# Getting "system.net.sockets.socketexception no such host is known" in Unity WebGL build

Tags: c#, sockets, email, unity-game-engine, smtpclient

Hello and thank you for taking the time to look help me with my problem.

I have been working on a small webgl thing within Unity that will send the user an email after they have done some stuff. I got it all built and ready to go, however when I built it and went to test it I get the socketexception error, when sending the email.

Here is the code I am using to send the email

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(myEmail);
mail.To.Add(userEmail.text);
mail.Subject = "Thanks for viewing the Webcam page at WilliamLeonSmith.com";
mail.Body = "This is an automated email to deliver the attached images that were created at WilliamLeonSmith.com";

SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
smtpServer.Port = 587;
smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(myEmail, pass) as ICredentialsByHost;
smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                { return true; };
smtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I am getting the problem in standalone build not webgl! why it is not working in standalone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** use **Sockets** or any other .Net network class on **WebGL**. This is for **security** reasons. Although, you can use Unity's `WWW` class.

You still have two Other Options.

[**EASY**]

**1**. **Re-write** the code you have in your question in **php**. Use Unity `WWW` class to send **message**(**toEmail, Subject, Body**)  to the **php** script. The **php** `script` will then **send** the actually **email** with the **information** it received from the **Unity App**.

If you **don't** want to learn **php**,you can **compile** the code in your question as a **console** app and then use it as **cgi** instead of **php**. `WWW` class can **communicate** with both **php** or **cgi** programs through `GET` or `POST` request.

[**HARD**]

**2**. You can implement **smtp protocol** or your own `MailMessage` class with **UnitySocketIO** library. https://github.com/NetEase/UnitySocketIO

Comment: say can you (not really relevant, but) use PubNub on webgl thingies ??  (i thought the op was asking about realtime networking in webgl)

Comment: Not really. He asked about sending email through Unity and that email library uses Socket which can't be used for Web BUILD.

Comment: Welp, Time to learn some PHP and get it to work with my program.

Comment: can't we send the email through player? i am getting SocketException: No such host is known.

Comment: @JoeBlow can unity standalone build send email? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479951/socketexception-no-such-host-is-known-failed-to-send-email-from-unity

Answer (score 1):

> Due to security implications, JavaScript code does not have direct access to IP Sockets to implement network connectivity. As a result, the .NET networking classes (ie, everything in the System.Net namespace, particularly System.Net.Sockets) are non-functional in WebGL.

According to unity Doc http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html

Hence the Error.