# Photon Client SDK and WebGL not working with multi-threading

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, unity-webgl

When I run game in unity editor, it working fine. 
When I compile as WebGL and open page in firefox, I have this error:

```
abort@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:3058219:43
_pthread_create@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:9360:2
__ZN6il2cpp2os10ThreadImpl3RunEPFvPvES2_ [il2cpp::os::ThreadImpl::Run(void (* (void*), void*)]@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:2653112:47
__ZN6il2cpp2os6Thread3RunEPFvPvES2_ [il2cpp::os::Thread::Run(void (*)(void*), void*)]@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:2874729:9
dynCall_iiii@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:2963923:9
invoke_iiii@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:17416:10
__ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System9Threading6Thread15Thread_internalEP12Il2CppThreadP14Il2CppDelegate [il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Threading::Thread::Thread_internal(Il2CppThread*, Il2CppDelegate*)]@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:1225486:14
_Thread_Start_m1419497481@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:1791638:7
_SocketTcp_Connect_m1201015870@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:2181642:3
__ZN16VirtFuncInvoker0IbE6InvokeEjPv [VirtFuncInvoker0::Invoke(unsigned int, void*)]@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:2811156:7
_TPeer_Connect_m3119387828@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:1340847:7
__ZN16VirtFuncInvoker2IbP8String_tS1_E6InvokeEjPvS1_S1_ [VirtFuncInvoker2::Invoke(unsigned int, void*, String_t*, String_t*)]@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:2745912:7
dynCall_iiiii@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:2942910:9
invoke_iiiii@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:16256:10
_PhotonPeer_Connect_m3702473380@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:1759101:8
__ZN16VirtFuncInvoker2IbP8String_tS1_E6InvokeEjPvS1_S1_ [VirtFuncInvoker2::Invoke(unsigned int, void*, String_t*, String_t*)]@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:2745912:7
_PhotonClient_ConnectToServer_m837296971@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:1097111:8
_NetWorker_ConnectToServer_m931114268@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:2760409:9
_Game_ConnectToServer_m115951967@blob:null/0e57772a-6990-46ba-afc3-1dc4b6f931bb:2770978:9
```

I think in this method: peer.Connect(connection, appName) the application try start new thread, but WebGL not supporting multi-threading

Comment: Will this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168828/getting-system-net-sockets-socketexception-no-such-host-is-known-in-unity-webg/36170343#36170343 help?

Comment: No. Photon must support WebGL, bun I don't know how. Their dll throw this error. Maybe for WebGL i don't mush using their dll? I don't know. From their site: "All Supported (Mobile, PC, Consoles, Web, WebGL)"

Comment: While photon is an admirable product, is there really any reason not to just use the networking built-in to Unity?

Comment: @Joe Blow , photon has nice realtime server. If i use unity networking, I must use on the server side: web service or unity instance, or our written server.

Comment: Hi @GLeBaTi - fair enough.  Say you should tick your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from exitgames developer:

> WebGL is not supported by current SDK v4.0.5.0 Please wait for next
>   release.