# SocketException: No such host is known - Failed to send email - unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, smtp

```
public void EmailSending() {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("xxx@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
    mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    smtpServer.Port = 587;
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "pw") as ICredentialsByHost;
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        { return true; };
    smtpServer.Send(mail);
    Debug.Log("success");
}
```

I am getting this error

> SocketException: No such host is known.
>
> System.Net.Dns.hostent_to_IPHostEntry (System.String h_name,
>   System.String[] h_aliases, System.String[] h_addrlist)

Comment: Where did you get that port setting? Have you tried port `465`

Comment: i change it 465, it showing still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> SocketException: No such host is known.
>
> ```
> System.Net.Dns.hostent_to_IPHostEntry (System.String h_name, System.String[] h_aliases, System.String[] h_addrlist)
> ```

was occurring due to proxy server. My IP was behind a proxy server, after assigning the direct internet access the code is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

if you have sending from anroid device then
I think you have same problem some time, make sure your android build asks for Internet Access permission.

Go to Android Player Settings, "Other settings" and look for Internet Access. It's "Auto" by default, set it to "Require".

Comment: I found some other issue, you have to set Api Compatibility Level to ".NET 2.0" instead of ".NET 2.0 Subset" under player settings. hope someone else can be helped by this as well.

Comment: Plz use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168828/getting-system-net-sockets-socketexception-no-such-host-is-known-in-unity-webg

Comment: This is about webgl i already check it i am not using webgl i am using an application

Answer (score 0):

SocketException: No such host is known.

Solution : The Internet is not available to perform the operation. Check your internet

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It was my very low internet connection.